# Force angular to reload on any route/location change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Is there anyway to do this?  That is, if I have a snippet such as:

```
$location.path("/splash");
```

Because I'm changing `$location`, angular will automatically reload the page (in order to reload all services/controllers).  Basically my problem is that I have stale controller/service data being passed around that is messing my app up.

Obviously something like this is just causing the page to infinitely reload:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(args){
   $route.reload();
});
```

Comment: Controller function will re-run when the route changes automatically. Do *not* store state in Services. Services should never have to reload. If you keep your state contained in controllers and directives, this should not be an issue.

Comment: I have this KeyboardService that tracks when keys are pressed and stores events.  It should only do it on page A.  When I click a link to page B, the KeyboardService messes with the functionality of the page.  Upon refreshing page B, the KeyboardService disappears and the page functions normally.

Comment: So instead have a KeytrackingFactory, not a "Service", instantiate it in the controller function. That way you get the separated code that you're aiming for, but a scoped Object to contain the state for only the relevant/instantiating controller.

Answer (score 3):

```
  $scope.navTo = function(url) {
    if ($location.path() === url) {
      $route.reload();
    } else {
      $location.path(url);
    }
  }
```

(ui-router):
`$state.go($state.current.name, $state.params, { reload: true });`

Comment: people had some other hacks where you could modify the source and call $state.reload() also, if that interests you.